# 3 foreign keys based on 2 columns in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, composite-key

I have a simple question to ask, can a MySQL table have 2 columns which serve as a composite foreign key and each column is a foreign key by itself (which gives us 3 foreign keys in total)?

Comment: You can have multiple foreign key in a table. Is this the question?

Comment: Not exactly. It's more like "Can i have 3 foreign keys in a MySQL table which has only 2 columns?"